# Animate div from right to left with variant width CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  min-width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  padding: 0 6px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

I want to animate the div from right to left in only CSS. The issue is that the inner `box` has a variant width (due to translations).

If I could do an animation similar to

```
from {
  right: 0;
}

to {
  left: 0;
}
```

it would be exactly what I need, but unfortunately this doesn't work.

How can I animate the inner div with a variant width from left to right using only CSS. The outer div also has a variant width.

**Edit:**

I would like the inner div to never move outside the outer div.

This is not a duplicate because the inner AND outer container have a variant/unknown width.

Comment: do you want to move the div from left to right?

Comment: @Viira Right to left, but I'm sure a solution for left to right can be applied to show right to left.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please see that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by starting with `right:100%` and finish to `right:0%`

**EDIT**
I've achieve this by using 2 different methods :

- by changing the `right` property and with using a `calc()` to prevent to box to go outside your container
- Use a wrapper who have the width of your container minus the width of your box and use `translateX` property for your animation.

```css
.container{
background-color:#ccc;
width:400px;
position:relative;
height:50px;
}

.big{
 width:600px;
}

.test1 .box{
 position:absolute;
 width:100px;
 height:100%;
 right:calc(100% - 100px);
 background-color:red;
 animation:to-right-1 1s linear forwards;
}

.test2 .wrapper{
position:relative;
width:calc(100% - 100px);
height:100%;
animation:to-right-2 1s linear forwards;
}

.test2 .box{
width:100px;
height:100%;
background-color:red;
}

@keyframes to-right-1{
  from{
    right:calc(100% - 100px);;
  }
  to{
    right:0px;
  }
}
@keyframes to-right-2{
  from{
    transform:translateX(0%);
  }
  to{
    transform:translateX(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container big">
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="test2">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper"><div class="box">Hello</div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="container big">
      <div class="wrapper"><div class="box">Hello</div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added an edit to my question.

Comment: I search out a way to ignore the from right percentage by using `calc()`, but it seems that calc break the animation but the calculated right are correct. Maybe you can add a little hack by using a wrapper on your box and use the `translateX`  property

Comment: @Acidic I update my answer. I've misspelled my calc, there's 2 working examples ;D

Comment: This does not support a variant width.

Comment: @Acidic yes it support variant width of your container not of your box

Answer (score 0):

After you define left and right in class.

```
transition-property: right, left;
transition-duration: 2s;
-webkit-transition-property: right, left; /* Safari */
-webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
```

right can be done like

```
right:calc(100% - 400px)
```

and use this to make it bigger as you go.

```
@-webkit-keyframes big {
    from { -webkit-transform: scale(.1,.1); }
    to { -webkit-transform:  scale(1,1); }
}
@keyframes big {
    from { transform: scale(.1,.1); }
    to { transform: scale(1,1); }
```

Use this fiddle as reference http://jsfiddle.net/MiKr13/aL7t2jvr/
}

Comment: This does not support a variant width.

Comment: @Acidic Okay let me see.

Comment: @Acidic You can use translate and transform in combination for variant width. Define the variant width in transform and use translate or transition to do the movement.

Comment: Can you please provide an example

Comment: Okay, let me see.

Comment: @Acidic I have given a fiddle. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyframes animation to animate'em.

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  min-width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  padding: 0 6px;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 32px;
}

  .navr{position:absolute; z-index:55; text-align:center; margin:0 auto; bottom:0%; cursor:pointer;}

.navr {
-webkit-animation-name: bump; 
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s; 
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1; 
animation-name: bump;
animation-duration: 2s;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
position:absolute;
left:0;
}

@keyframes bump {
0%   {right:-100%;}
   
100% {right:85%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box navr">HELLO</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would like the div to stop on the left without being cut off, thank you though.

Comment: ok wait lemme update.

Comment: Ok no problem  !

Comment: I have updated my answer please see that too

Comment: This does not support a variant width.

Comment: ok wait lemme create a jsfiddle for ya

Answer (score 0):

If you use variant width you can use the element's width to position them.

Here the class `.animated`  has a width of `50px;` so we can move it's postion from `left:100%` to `left:50px` instead of giving `left:0`

because the element `.animate` has the `absolute` position. That's why we are giving it's width as position here.

```css
    .container {
     position: relative;
     width: 80%;
     height: 50px;
     border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .animated {
     position: absolute;
     width: 50px;
     height: 100%;
     background-color: red;
     animation: .5s linear 0s slide 1;
    }

    @keyframes slide {
      from { left: 100%; }
      to {
        left: 50px;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
      }
    }
```

```html
    <div class=container>
    <div class=animated>hello
    </div></div>
```